Imported resource from 2nd branch of filament into 3rd got error
On laravel 10 app with filament ^3.20-stable I imported resource from the second branch of filament
and got error :
Filament\Tables\Columns\SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn::Filament\Tables\Columns\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($media) must be of type Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media, App\Models\Media given

In resource file app/Filament/Resources/PageContentResource.php I fixed all blocks, where phpstorm
showed error and it has code :
namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat;
use App\Filament\Resources\PageContentResource\Pages;

use App\Library\AppLocale;
use App\Library\Facades\DateConv;
use App\Models\PageContent;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Closure;


use Filament\Forms\Components\Card;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Placeholder;
use Filament\Forms\Components\RichEditor;
use Filament\Forms\Components\SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload;
use Filament\Forms\Components\TextInput;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Toggle;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Section;


use Filament\Forms\Set;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Filament\Tables\Actions\BulkAction;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Columns\TextColumn;
use Filament\Tables\Enums\ActionsPosition;
use Filament\Tables\Filters\Filter;
use Filament\Tables\Table;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/* NSN COMMENTED */

class PageContentResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = PageContent::class;
    protected static ?string $recordTitleAttribute = 'title';
    protected static ?string $navigationGroup = 'ContentA';
    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-document-duplicate';
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $localeFields = self::getLocaleInputFields();

        return $form
            ->schema([
                Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        // Section with all locale fields
                        Section::make('Locales')
                            ->schema($localeFields)
                            ->columns(2),

                        Card::make()
                            ->schema([
                                // Depending on value selected in this field some fields are shown or hidden
                                Select::make('content_type')
                                    ->options(PageContent::getContentTypeSelectionItems(false))
                                    ->required()
                                    ->reactive()
                                    ->afterStateUpdated(function (callable $set) {
                                        $set('ordering', null);
                                        $set('auth_required', null);
                                    }),

                                TextInput::make('ordering')
                                    ->lazy()
                                    // ordering field is visible only when content_type = F=>FAQ,
                                    ->hidden(function (Closure $get, ?PageContent $record) {
                                        if (empty($get('content_type'))) {
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        return $get('content_type') != 'F';
                                    })
                                    ->numeric(),
                                Section::make('Image')
                                    ->schema([
                                        SpatieMediaLibraryFileUpload::make('media')
                                            ->collection(config('app.media_app_name')),
                                    ])
                                    ->hidden(function (Closure $get, ?PageContent $record) {
                                        if (empty($get('content_type'))) {
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        return $get('content_type') === 'B' or $get('content_type') === 'F';
                                    })
                                    ->collapsible(),

                                Toggle::make('published')
                                    ->label('Is published')
                                    ->helperText('If published, this page content will be hidden from all frontend pages.')
                                    ->default(false)
                                    ->hintColor('danger'),

                                Toggle::make('auth_required')
                                    ->label('Is auth required')
                                    ->helperText('If auth required, this page content will be will be visible only for logged user.')
                                    ->default(false)
                                    // is visible if only content_type === 'B'/BLOG
                                    // auth_required field is visible only when content_type = 'B'/BLOG,
                                    ->hidden(function (Closure $get, ?PageContent $record) {
                                        if (empty($get('content_type'))) {
                                            return false;
                                        }

                                        return $get('content_type') != 'B';
                                    })
                                    ->hintColor('danger'),

                            ])
                            ->columns(2),

                    ])
                    ->columnSpan(['lg' => fn(?PageContent $record) => $record === null ? 3 : 2]),

                Section::make()
                    ->schema([
                        // is visible if only content_type === 'B'/BLOG or content_type === 'P'/Page(About/contactUs)or content_type === 'N'/NEWS)
                        // is hidden if only content_type === 'F'/FAQ
                        Section::make(__('miscellaneous'))
                            ->label('Miscellaneous')
                            ->description(__('You can not edit these fields'))
                            ->schema([
                                TextInput::make('id')->disabled()->dehydrated(false)
                                    ->hidden(fn(?PageContent $record) => $record === null),
                                TextInput::make('slug')->lazy() /*->disabled()->*/ /*dehydrated(false)*/ ,

                                Placeholder::make('creator')
                                    ->content(fn(?PageContent $record
                                    ): ?string => $record->getAttribute('creator')->name)
                                    ->hidden(fn(?PageContent $record) => $record === null),
                                Placeholder::make('banner_clicked_counts_count')
                                    ->content(fn(?PageContent $record
                                    ): int => $record->getAttribute('banner_clicked_counts_count') ?? 0)
                                    ->hidden(function (Closure $get, ?PageContent $record) {
                                        if (empty($get('content_type'))) {
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                        return $get('content_type') === 'F';
                                    }),

                                    Placeholder::make('created_at')
                                        ->label('Created at')
                                        ->content(fn(PageContent $record) => DateConv::getFormattedDateTime(
                                            $record->getAttribute('created_at'), DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT))
                                        ->hidden(fn(?PageContent $record
                                        ) => ($record === null or $record->getAttribute('created_at') === null)),

                                    Placeholder::make('updated_at')
                                        ->label('Last modified at')
                                        ->content(fn(PageContent $record) => DateConv::getFormattedDateTime(
                                            $record->getAttribute('updated_at'), DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT))
                                        ->hidden(fn(?PageContent $record
                                        ) => ($record === null or $record->getAttribute('updated_at') === null)),
                            ])
                            ->collapsible(),

                        // Tags/Categories are visible if only content_type === 'B'/BLOG or content_type === 'P'/Page(About/contactUs)or content_type === 'N'/NEWS)
                        // Tags/Categories are hidden if only content_type === 'F'/FAQ
                        Section::make(__('Tags/Categories'))
                            ->description(__('You can edit Tags/Categories'))
                            ->schema([
                            ])
                            ->collapsible()
                            ->hidden(function (Closure $get, ?PageContent $record) {
                                if (empty($get('content_type'))) {
                                    return false;
                                }

                                return $get('content_type') === 'F';
                            }),
                    ])
                    ->columnSpan(['lg' => 1]),

                // is visible if only content_type === 'B'/BLOG or content_type === 'N'/NEWS)
                // is hidden if only content_type === 'F'/FAQ  or 'P'/Page(About/contactUs)
                Section::make('Assigned banner categories')
                    ->schema([
                    ])
                    ->columns(1)
                    ->hidden(function (Closure $get, ?PageContent $record) {
                        if (empty($get('content_type'))) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        return $get('content_type') === 'F' or $get('content_type') === 'P';
                    }),
            ])
            ->columns(3);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('id')->sortable(),

                Tables\Columns\SpatieMediaLibraryImageColumn::make('page-content-image')
                    ->label('Image')
                    ->collection(config('app.media_app_name')),

                TextColumn::make('title')->sortable()->searchable(),

                Tables\Columns\IconColumn::make('published')
                    ->label('Published')
                    ->boolean()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->trueColor('success')
                    ->falseColor('warning')
                    ->tooltip('If page content is not published it will not be visible on frontend pages'),

                TextColumn::make('creator.name')->sortable()->label('Creator'),
                TextColumn::make('banner_clicked_counts_count')->label('Clicked counts')->alignment('right'),

                TextColumn::make('ordering')->sortable()->alignment('right'),
                TextColumn::make('created_at')->dateTime(DateConv::getDateTimeFormat(\App\Enums\DatetimeOutputFormat::AS_TEXT))->sortable()
            ])
            ->filters([
                Filter::make('filter_published')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('published', true))
                    ->indicator('Published'),
                Filter::make('filter_unpublished')
                    ->query(fn(Builder $query): Builder => $query->where('published', false))
                    ->indicator('Unpublished'),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make()
            ], position: ActionsPosition::BeforeColumns)
            ->bulkActions( // bulk Actions to publish/unpublish page contents
                [
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                    BulkAction::make('Publish')
                        ->label('Publish selected')
                        ->color('success')
                        ->size('lg')
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-document-plus')
                        ->action(function (Collection $records, array $data): void {
                            foreach ($records as $pageContentRecord) {
                                $pageContentRecord->setAttribute('updated_at', Carbon::now(config('app.timezone')));
                                $pageContentRecord->setAttribute('published', true);
                                $pageContentRecord->save();
                            }
                            Notification::make()
                                ->title("Selected post content(s) are published !")
                                ->success()
                                ->send();

                        })
                        ->deselectRecordsAfterCompletion(),

                    BulkAction::make('Unpublish')
                        ->label('Unpublish selected')
                        ->color('warning')
                        ->size('lg')
                        ->icon('heroicon-o-document-minus')
                        ->action(function (Collection $records, array $data): void {
                            foreach ($records as $pageContentRecord) {
                                $pageContentRecord->setAttribute('updated_at', Carbon::now(config('app.timezone')));
                                $pageContentRecord->setAttribute('published', false);
                                $pageContentRecord->save();
                            }
                            Notification::make()
                                ->title("Selected post content(s) are unpublished !")
                                ->danger()
                                ->send();
                        })
                        ->deselectRecordsAfterCompletion(),

                ]
            );

    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListPageContents::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreatePageContent::route('/create'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditPageContent::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }

    public static function getGlobalSearchResultTitle(Model $record): string
    {
        $defaultLocale = AppLocale::getDefaultLocale();
        $text          = $record->getTranslation('title', $defaultLocale, false) . ', status: ' .
                         PageContent::getPublishedLabel($record->getAttribute('published'));

        return $text;
    }

    protected static function getLocaleInputFields(): array
    {
        [$locales] = Arr::divide(AppLocale::getAppLocaleSelectionItems(false));
        $localeFields = [];
        foreach ($locales as $locale) { // show multi language elements for all locales of the app
            $localeLabel    = AppLocale::getAppLocaleLabel($locale);
            $imgUrl         = '<img src="' . AppLocale::getLocaleImageUrlByLocale($locale) . '" title="' . $localeLabel . '" alt="' . $localeLabel . '">';
            $localeFields[] = TextInput::make('title_' . $locale)
                ->afterStateHydrated(function (TextInput $component, $state) use ($locale) {
                    $pageContentModel = $component->getModelInstance();
                    if ( ! empty($pageContentModel->title)) { // Fill title field only in "edit" mode : get string value from json field
                        $component->state($pageContentModel->getTranslation('title', $locale, false));
                    }
                })
                ->lazy()
                ->afterStateUpdated(fn (Set $set, ?string $state) => $set('slug', Str::slug($state)))

                ->label('Title in ' . $localeLabel)
                ->helperText($imgUrl)
                ->required()
                ->minLength(2)
                ->maxLength(255);
            $localeFields[] = RichEditor::make('content_shortly_' . $locale)
                ->afterStateHydrated(function (RichEditor $component, $state) use ($locale) {
                    $pageContentModel = $component->getModelInstance();
                    if ( ! empty($pageContentModel->title)) { // Fill content_shortly field only in "edit" mode : get string value from json field
                        $component->state($pageContentModel->getTranslation('content_shortly', $locale,
                            false));
                    }
                })
                ->label('Content shortly in ' . $localeLabel)
                ->helperText($imgUrl)
                ->required()
                ->columnSpan('full');
            $localeFields[] = RichEditor::make('content_' . $locale)
                ->afterStateHydrated(function (RichEditor $component, $state) use ($locale) {
                    $pageContentModel = $component->getModelInstance();
                    if ( ! empty($pageContentModel->title)) { // Fill content field only in "edit" mode : get string value from json field
                        $component->state($pageContentModel->getTranslation('content', $locale,
                            false));
                    }
                })
                ->label('Content in ' . $localeLabel)
                ->helperText($imgUrl)
                ->required()
                ->columnSpan('full');
        }

        return $localeFields;
    }

}

and model app/Models/PageContent :
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;

use Spatie\Translatable\HasTranslations;

class PageContent extends Model implements HasMedia
{
    use HasTranslations;
    use HasFactory;
    use InteractsWithMedia;

    protected $table = 'page_contents';
    
    public const MEDIA_COLLECTION_NAME = 'filament_banners_media';
    public const MEDIA_TRASH_COLLECTION_NAME = 'trash';
    
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'slug', 'content_shortly', 'content', 'published', 'content_type', 'auth_required', 'creator_id', 'ordering', 'updated_at'];
    public $translatable = ['title', 'content_shortly', 'content'];
    protected $casts
        = [
            'published' => 'boolean',
            'auth_required' => 'boolean',
            'updated_at' => 'datetime',
            'created_at' => 'datetime',
        ];
    
    public const STATUS_PUBLISHED = 1;
    public const STATUS_UNPUBLISHED = 0;
    
    private static $statusSelectionItems
        = [
            self::STATUS_PUBLISHED => 'Published',
            self::STATUS_UNPUBLISHED => 'Not published'
        ];
    
    public static function getPublishedSelectionItems(bool $keyReturn = true): array
    {
        $resArray = [];
        foreach (self::$statusSelectionItems as $key => $value) {
            if ($keyReturn) {
                $resArray[] = ['key' => $key, 'label' => $value];
            } else {
                $resArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        
        return $resArray;
    }
    
    public static function getPublishedLabel(bool $active = null): string
    {
        if ( ! empty(self::$statusSelectionItems[$active])) {
            return self::$statusSelectionItems[$active];
        }
        
        return self::$statusSelectionItems[self::STATUS_UNPUBLISHED];
    }
    
    // auth_required
    public const AUTH_REQUIRED_YES = 1;
    public const AUTH_REQUIRED_NOT = 0;
    
    private static $authRequiredSelectionItems
        = [
            self::AUTH_REQUIRED_YES => 'Authorization is required',
            self::AUTH_REQUIRED_NOT => 'Authorization is not required'
        ];
    
    public static function getAuthRequiredSelectionItems(bool $keyReturn = true): array
    {
        $resArray = [];
        foreach (self::$authRequiredSelectionItems as $key => $value) {
            if ($keyReturn) {
                $resArray[] = ['key' => $key, 'label' => $value];
            } else {
                $resArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        
        return $resArray;
    }
    
    public static function getAuthRequiredLabel(?bool $authRequired = null): string
    {
        if ( ! empty(self::$authRequiredSelectionItems[$authRequired])) {
            return self::$authRequiredSelectionItems[$authRequired];
        }
        
        return self::$authRequiredSelectionItems[self::AUTH_REQUIRED_NOT];
    }
    
    public const CONTENT_TYPE_PAGE = 'P';
    public const CONTENT_TYPE_BLOG = 'B';
    public const CONTENT_TYPE_FAQ = 'F';
    public const CONTENT_TYPE_NEWS = 'N';
    
    private static $contentTypeSelectionItems
        = [
            self::CONTENT_TYPE_PAGE => 'Page(About/contactUs)',
            self::CONTENT_TYPE_BLOG => 'Blog',
            self::CONTENT_TYPE_FAQ => 'FAQ',
            self::CONTENT_TYPE_NEWS => 'News',
        ];
    
    public static function getContentTypeSelectionItems(bool $keyReturn = true): array
    {
        $resArray = [];
        foreach (self::$contentTypeSelectionItems as $key => $value) {
            if ($keyReturn) {
                $resArray[] = ['key' => $key, 'label' => $value];
            } else {
                $resArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        
        return $resArray;
    }
    
    public static function getContentTypeLabel(?string $contentType = null): string
    {
        if ( ! empty(self::$contentTypeSelectionItems[$contentType])) {
            return self::$contentTypeSelectionItems[$contentType];
        }
        
        return self::$contentTypeSelectionItems[self::CONTENT_TYPE_PAGE];
    }
    
    public function scopeGetBySlug($query, $slug = null)
    {
        if ( ! empty($slug)) {
            $query->where($this->table . '.slug', $slug);
        }
        
        return $query;
    }
    
    public function scopeGetByPublished($query, $published = null)
    {
        if ( ! isset($published) or strlen($published) === 0) {
            return $query;
        }
        
        return $query->where($this->table . '.published', $published);
    }
    
    public function scopeGetByContentType($query, $contentType = null)
    {
        if ( ! isset($contentType) or strlen($contentType) === 0) {
            return $query;
        }
        
        return $query->where($this->table . '.content_type', $contentType);
    }
    
    public function scopeGetByCreatorId($query, $creatorId)
    {
        if ( ! empty($creatorId)) {
            return $query->where($this->table . '.creator_id', $creatorId);
        }
    }
    
    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'creator_id', 'id');
    }
    
    public function pageContentHasBannerCategories(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->HasMany(\App\Models\PageContentHasBannerCategory::class);
    }
    
    public function pageContentHasPageContentTags(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->HasMany(\App\Models\PageContentHasPageContentTag::class);
    }
}

How this error can be fixed ?
